# Transforming from NAD83(2011) or from WGS84 gives the same result (pyproj)

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, pyproj, nad83, transform

I'm trying to transform (using pyproj) the same coordinates, first from WGS84, and then from NAD83(2011), and I'm getting the same result:

```
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer

from_wgs84_transformer = Transformer.from_crs(CRS("WGS84"), CRS("epsg:6415"), allow_ballpark=False)
from_nad83_transformer = Transformer.from_crs(CRS("NAD83(2011)"), CRS("epsg:6415"), allow_ballpark=False)
```

```
>>> from_wgs84_transformer.transform(41.15240653663834, -122.85890995637374)
(1927909.814711512, 702339.7864515218)

>>> from_nad83_transformer.transform(41.15240653663834, -122.85890995637374)
(1927909.814711512, 702339.7864515218)
```

Can someone explain why, and also how to fix the code?

Comment: I could not find any example about the usage as ` Transformer.from_crs(CRS("WGS84"),...`. Where did you find the documentation for that syntax?

Comment: How to you suggest to create the transformation?
https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/_modules/pyproj/transformer.html#Transformer.from_crs

Comment: Do you have the transportation grids installed? https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/transformation_grids.html

Comment: One transformation/operation path could be 7666 which is wgs84(G1762) to ITRF2008 (null transformation) and then 7807, ITRF2008 to NAD83(2011) which is time-based so you need a data epoch or just use the base epoch of the transformation.

Comment: @mkennedy How can I make sure this is the correct path to take?
btw, can you recommend a source (book/blog/etc) where I can learn all this stuff to its core?

Answer (score 1):

You get that result because for Proj NAD83(2011) and WGS 84 mean the same. You can get a full report by testing the transformation with Projinfo.

```
projinfo -s epsg:6318 -t epsg:4326

Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

EPSG:9774, NAD83(2011) to WGS 84 (1), 2.0 m ...
...

PROJ string:
+proj=noop
...
SCOPE["(null/copy) Approximation for medium and low accuracy
applications assuming equality between plate-fixed static 
and earth-fixed dynamic CRSs, ignoring static/dynamic CRS 
differences."]
...
    REMARK["For many purposes NAD83(2011) can be considered
to be coincident with WGS 84. This approximation ignores 
the ~2.2m offset of NAD83 from the geocentre, the low 
accuracy of the WGS 84 ensemble and the application 
of tectonic plate motion to WGS 84 data."]]
```

Unfortunately I do not know which tools can handle the terms that Proj ignores.

Comment: They're not the same. NAD83(2011) is plate-fixed, while WGS 84 (and ITRFxx) is not. There's about 1-2 m difference between the 2 systems. That transformation has a 2 m accuracy because it's not taking the differences into account.

Comment: And for taking into account the differences also the epoch of the dynamic system should be known. It seems that Proj and GDAL has nowadays support for coordinate epoch https://gdal.org/user/coordinate_epoch.html.

Comment: @user30184 do you know how to do this in pyproj? I didn't find any reference to "coordinate epoch" in pyproj

Comment: Maybe you could try for example EPSG:7665 instead of EPSG:4326. If I understand right it has the epoch included somehow.