High accuracy (~2cm) transformation from WGS84 to NAD83
I am trying to transform some coordinates from WGS84 to NAD83. This is used for performing testing of an autonomous vehicle, so it is important the transformation is the highest accuracy possible. We have an RTK system on the vehicle, so similar accuracy (~2cm) is desired for the coordinate transformation.
I tried using a few different software packages, but I've settled on the bash bindings to proj for now, since it seems to give me the most access to debug info and settings.
The issue I have is that the coordinates aren't actually transformed. For example:
echo 42 -85.5 | cs2cs +proj=latlon +datum=WGS84 +epoch=2023.0 +to +proj=latlon +datum=NAD83 +epoch=2024.0
42dE    85d30'S 0.000

Debugging further, I found this command to inspect the source of the transformation data being used internally:
projinfo -s WGS84 -t NAD83 --bbox -84,42.5,-84,42.5 --spatial-test intersects
Candidate operations found: 2
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

INVERSE(DERIVED_FROM(EPSG)):1722, Inverse of NAD83 to WGS 84 (26), 2.0 m, United States (USA) - Michigan.

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad
  +step +inv +proj=hgridshift +grids=us_noaa_mihpgn.tif
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

WKT2:2019 string:
COORDINATEOPERATION["Inverse of NAD83 to WGS 84 (26)",
    SOURCECRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2296)"],
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["NAD83",
            DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
                ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4269]]],
    METHOD["Inverse of HORIZONTAL_SHIFT_GTIFF"],
    PARAMETERFILE["Latitude and longitude difference file","us_noaa_mihpgn.tif"],
    OPERATIONACCURACY[2.0],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["(null/copy) Approximation for medium and low accuracy applications assuming equality between plate-fixed static and earth-fixed dynamic CRSs, ignoring static/dynamic CRS differences."],
        AREA["United States (USA) - Michigan."],
        BBOX[41.69,-90.42,48.32,-82.13]],
    ID["INVERSE(DERIVED_FROM(EPSG))",1722],
    REMARK["Parameter files are from NAD83 to NAD83(HARN) (14) (code 1487) assuming that NAD83(HARN) is equivalent to WGS 84 within the accuracy of the transformation."]]

I interpret this as: "WGS84 and NAD83 are pretty close, let's just assume the coordinates are the same and the error will be less than 2 meters, which is good enough for most applications"
If that isn't good enough for my application, what do I do? I figure I need to download or setup remote access to a higher accuracy transform? Where would I look? Is it reasonable to expect to find a higher accuracy transform for free?

Does this help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470635/transforming-from-nad832011-or-from-wgs84-gives-the-same-result-pyproj?

WGS84 high accuracy coordinates are military-only. Check what the RTK system is actually reporting. In the US, it might be ITRFxx or NAD83(2011). The latter is current for the US.

@mkennedy, yes our RTK system operates in NAD83 but a 3rd party that did a survey for us did it in WGS84.

I did find this transform, which appears to actually include a transformation, but it isn't clear to me how to use it and if it accounts for epoch or perhaps picks an average epoch (resulting in the confidence level)

It seems to me that the highest accuracy tool is NOAA's HTDP tool, so I will use that. I would have liked to use Proj or GDAL to better fit with a software-driven workflow, but the online tool will suffice.

@Jimbalaya I would go back to the 3rd party and push them on this. What was their workflow? Did they just call the data WGS84? Or did they use a transformation? If so, which one and/or what software did they use? If they used NGS control points or WAAS or what?
